# How to disable internal ordering in SAS?

Tags: loops, variables, macros, sas

Suppose I have a pipe delimited text file with two columns:

```
LIBRARY_NAME|TABLE_NAME
A.|ZZZ
A.|XXX
B.|QQQ
B.|AAA
B.|MNO
B.|OPQ
```

I import the file using INFILE statement and assign all values of both columns to macro variables &LIB and &TAB respectively.

```
/* COUNT THE TABLES IN ORDER TO BE ABLE TO LOOP THROUGH THEM LATER: */
PROC SQL;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :TABLE_C FROM TABLE_NAMES; 
    /* DELETE LEADING BLANKS FROM THE COUNT: */
    %LET TABLE_COUNT = &TABLE_C; 

QUIT;


/* MAKE A LIST OF THE LIBRARY & TABLE NAMES: */
PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    SELECT 
        LIBRARY_NAME

        INTO 
            :LIB1 - :LIB&TABLE_COUNT

        FROM 
            WORK.TABLE_NAMES;

    SELECT 
        DISTINCT TABLE_NAME

        INTO 
            :TAB1 - :TAB&TABLE_COUNT

        FROM 
            WORK.TABLE_NAMES;

QUIT;
```

So in essence, I now have two "arrays" containing all the libraries and tables. 
Now I want to do this DO LOOP inside a macro which goes to the relevant libraries and tables, retrieves relevant data and creates relevant tables in WORK library:

```
%DO N = 1 %TO &COUNT;

    PROC SQL;

        CREATE TABLE WORK.&&TAB&N AS 

            SELECT
                *

                FROM
                    &&LIB&N.&&TAB&N

                WHERE
                    AGE > 50;

    QUIT;

%END;
```

The problem is, it only creates some of the tables. I got this error saying tables A.AAA and A.MNO do not exist. Which is true. So somehow, SAS is mixing up those two columns or order of them. Instead of doing the loop in the order how they appear in the source file and combining the right library with right table, it somehow mixes it up. 
**EDIT:** I am now pretty sure SAS sorts both "arrays" of library and tables names automatically before the DO LOOP which is obiously not very good for me as it mixes it up all. 
How can I force SAS to NOT automatically ORDER the values so that the original order of both columns is retained?
**EDIT2:** When I change the order of the libraries in the source text file (i.e. put the B tables in front of A tables), it works. Really strange.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to post the code you are using to read the pipe and to create the array..

Comment: I can assure you that sas is not sorting those macro 'array's, as they are not actually arrays - just a numbered set of individual macro variables.

Comment: You are creating work dataset name using just the member name from your input list. But your input list has datasets from more than one source libref.  Is it possible that you are just overwriting the data form A.XXX with the data from B.XXX?

Comment: Added the code that creates those two numbered sets of individual macro variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISTINCT is what orders your data. SQL can't determine what's unique without a sort of some kind. 
You also don't need to know the number of items ahead of time, SAS will create enough macro variables by default. 
You can avoid this by creating a single list of macro variables.

```
 Proc SQL noprint;
     Select distinct catx('.', library_name, table_name) into :ref_list1-
 From work.table_names;
 Quit;

%put &ref_list1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just skip the PROC SQL code. Just generate the macro variables when you read in the source file.

```
data table_names ;
  infile 'myfile' dsd dlm='|' firstobs=2 truncover ;
  length library_name $9 table_name $32 ;
  input library_name table_name ;
  call symputx(cats('LIB',_n_),library_name);
  call symputx(cats('TAB',_n_),table_name);
run;
```